# Earn rewards for participating vs Earn rewards by participating

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, collocation

Is it correct to say:

> You can earn rewards **for** participating in the company's wellness program.

I'm inclined to change it to

> You can earn rewards **by** participating in the company's wellness program.

I can't figure out if there is a difference in meaning.

Comment: It's correct either way, but it has nothing to do with being a gerund. It's the predicates in the sentence: _earn_ allows _by_ to introduce a means clause (_He earned something by participating_), while _reward_ allows _for_ to introduce a means clause (_There is a reward for participating_). Since both predicates are present, either preposition is allowed.